# "nothing ‘family values’” or “no ‘family values’"?

Tags: grammar, negation, quotations

I have encountered the construction *nothing something* in [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/2h4DkpFP_aw).

> Also, he once acted with a monkey and there is **nothing** “family values” about that.

Should *no* have been used there instead of *nothing*?

Explain that grammar for me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `nothing [adjective phrase] about X`  is a colloquialism. It is a way of saying that the modifier does not apply to X.

> The restaurant had a glass-enclosed veranda with the shades pulled down because of the sun.  There was nothing *al fresco* about it.
>
> The film was very tame. There was nothing "X-rated" about it.

The speaker in your example is tweaking the pattern by using the noun-phrase "family values" in place of an adjectival modifier.  It is elliptical:

Acting with a monkey does not promote so-called "family values".

The adjectival modifier "[promoting] family values" is not applicable.